# NativeScript error when trying to build on virtual device

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript, nativescript-angular

I searched all over the other similar questions, but none that could help me on solve the problem. I've added nativescript to an existing Angular 6.1 project, installed the android virtual device, follow all steps indicated in docs but when I launch

```
tns run android --bundle
```

app on virtual device give me the following error:

```
System.err: Calling js method onCreate failed
System.err:
System.err: TypeError: Cannot read property 'create' of undefined
System.err: File: "file:///data/data/org.nativescript.ngsample/files/app/vendor.js, line: 12299, column: 14
```

The same process on newly created project, works well. How can I solve this? 
Anyone can help me, please?

Comment: Does the default templates work? This seems something purely related to your code, try to run without `--bundle` option to get a better pointer on the error.

Comment: Which version of {NS} are you using?

Comment: Did u find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

It seems a NativeScript issue, I have found the solution here: https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/6552

To fix that you have to update the versions of:

1. typescript to ~2.8.0 or above
2. tns-core-modules to 5.0.2
3. nativescript-dev-webpack to 0.17.0

Update it with:

```
npm install typescript@latest
npm install tns-core-modules@latest
npm install nativescript-dev-webpack@latest
```

Then you can check you are using the correct versions, looking in the package.json of your project.